# How to work with json object and jsonarray

Tags: java, android, json

I have this JSON response:

```json
"objects":{
  "5": [
    [
      {
        "id_lot_espace": 0,
        "id_lot_objet": "0",
        "id_objet_piece": 0,
        "params": {
          "auto": "1",
          "objLink": "0",
          "setpointM": "7",
          "setpoint0": "21",
          "setpoint1": "19",
          "setpointA": "16",
          "tempSocialJ": "19",
          "tempSocialN": "17",
          "tempMin": "7",
          "tempMax": "30",
          "tempFrom": "2018-10-15",
          "tempTo": "2019-04-15"
        },
        "label": "migo",
        "pieceLabel": "Pièce principale",
        "objLabel": "Tête thermostatique",
        "code": "zwave_device_fab36177_node6_thermostat_setpoint_heating",
        "renommable": "0",
        "id_famille": 5,
        "reveil_possible": "1",
        "id_type_espace": "25",
        "principal": "1",
        "rights": 1
      }
    ]
  ],

    "17": {
      "381": {
        "19": {
          "id_lot_espace": "381",
          "id_lot_objet": "0",
          "id_objet_piece": "19",
          "params": "",
          "label": "Pièce principale - Tête thermostatique",
          "pieceLabel": "Pièce principale",
          "objLabel": "Tête thermostatique",
          "code": "",
          "renommable": "0",
          "id_famille": "17",
          "reveil_possible": "1",
          "id_type_espace": "25",
          "principal": "1",
          "rights": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to access `pieceLabel` in each element.  Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

```js
job = new JSONObject(responseContent);
JSONObject object = job.getJSONObject("objects");

Iterator<String> it = object.keys();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  String key = it.next();
  JSONObject obj1 = object.getJSONObject(key);

  Iterator<String> it1 = obj1.keys();
  while (it1.hasNext()) {
    String key1 = it1.next();
    JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject(key1);

    Iterator<String> it2 = obj2.keys();
    while (it2.hasNext()) {
      String key2 = it2.next();
      final JSONObject obj3 = obj2.getJSONObject(key2);
      String pieceLabel = String.valueOf(obj3.get("pieceLabel"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This JSON is not valid, man...

Comment: Yeah, it's not valid

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin Why not?

Comment: @cricket_007 , now it's valid, watch edit history

Comment: I can't even understand the structure if this JSON. I suppose that pattern matching is the only option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate your unstructured json recursively and check every key.

Here is a working example to show you how to achieve what you want to do:

```
public class Main {

    private static List<String> values = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test.json"))));

            findValues(jsonObject);

            values.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void findValues(Object root) {

        if (root instanceof JSONObject) {
            Iterator<String> keys = ((JSONObject)root).keys();

            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();

                if ("pieceLabel".equals(key)) {
                    values.add(((JSONObject)root).getString(key));
                }
                else {
                    Object o = ((JSONObject)root).get(key);
                    findValues(o);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (root instanceof JSONArray) {
            for (Object o : (JSONArray)root) {
                findValues(o);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

test.json file contains your example json.

Output is :

```
Pièce principale
Pièce principale
```

Change the values and order of keys and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your json its having issue. You can use many tools online to check your json if its proper or not.
I usually use https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

---

### Corrected Json

```
 [
      [
        {
      "id_lot_espace": 0,
      "id_lot_objet": "0",
      "id_objet_piece": 0,
      "params": {
        "auto": "1",
        "objLink": "0",
        "setpointM": "7",
        "setpoint0": "21",
        "setpoint1": "19",
        "setpointA": "16",
        "tempSocialJ": "19",
        "tempSocialN": "17",
        "tempMin": "7",
        "tempMax": "30",
        "tempFrom": "2018-10-15",
        "tempTo": "2019-04-15"
        },
      "label": "migo",
      "pieceLabel": "Pièce principale",
      "objLabel": "Tête thermostatique",
      "code": "zwave_device_fab36177_node6_thermostat_setpoint_heating",
      "renommable": "0",
      "id_famille": 5,
      "reveil_possible": "1",
      "id_type_espace": "25",
      "principal": "1",
      "rights": 1
     }
    ]
    ]


    {
  "17": {
    "381": {
      "19": {
        "id_lot_espace": "381",
        "id_lot_objet": "0",
        "id_objet_piece": "19",
        "params": "",
        "label": "Pièce principale - Tête thermostatique",
        "pieceLabel": "Pièce principale",
        "objLabel": "Tête thermostatique",
        "code": "",
        "renommable": "0",
        "id_famille": "17",
        "reveil_possible": "1",
        "id_type_espace": "25",
        "principal": "1",
        "rights": 1
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

---

### Final Code

```
 try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(sss.trim());
        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            Log.d("vt","output1 "+key);
            JSONObject obj1 = jObject.getJSONObject(key);
            Iterator<String> it1 = obj1.keys();

            while (it1.hasNext()) {
                String key1 = it1.next();
                Log.d("vt","output2 "+key1);
                JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject(key1);

                Iterator<String> it2 = obj2.keys();
                while (it2.hasNext()) {
                    String key2 = it2.next();
                    Log.d("vt","output3 "+key2);
                    final JSONObject obj3 = obj2.getJSONObject(key2);
                    String pieceLabel =          String.valueOf(obj3.get("pieceLabel"));
                    Log.d("vt","final "+pieceLabel);
                }
            }
        }

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("vt","error  "+e.getMessage());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed your json through https://jsoneditoronline.org and did not find any error.

I used json-simple which can be found here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1

My example is below with no loops.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jobj = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(".json"),"UTF-8"));
        jobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jobj2 = (JSONObject) jobj.get("object"); // outer object.
    JSONObject jobj3 = (JSONObject) jobj2.get("17"); // nested object.
    JSONObject jobj4 = (JSONObject) jobj3.get("381"); // nested object.
    JSONObject jobj5 = (JSONObject) jobj4.get("19"); // nested object.
    System.out.println(jobj5.get("pieceLabel")); // Returns the value to where the specified key is mapped.

    JSONArray jsarry = (JSONArray) jobj.get("5"); // Json Array.
    JSONArray jsarry2 = (JSONArray) jsarry.get(0); // nested Json Array.
    JSONObject nestedjsobj = (JSONObject) jsarry2.get(0); // nested object.
    System.out.println(nestedjsobj.get("pieceLabel"));  // Returns the value to where the specified key is mapped.
}
```

output:

```
Pièce principale
Pièce principale
```